# Ionic - Move to another state

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-click

I am developing an ionic application in which I stuck at navigation from one state to another state .

I have mentioned the way I tried below

In **index.html**  ,

```
<body ng-app="starter">
<ion-pane>
    <div>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Registration</h1>
    </ion-header-bar> 
    <ion-content padding="true">
     <div class="list card" ng-controller="DemographicsController">

     <div   style="margin-left:15%;margin-right:15%;">
          <button class="button  icon-left ion-close-circled  button-block button-assertive" ng-click="moveToNextPage()">Move to Next Page</button>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
     </div>
    </ion-pane>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
var module=angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova','ngAutocomplete'])


module.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$ionicConfigProvider) {

 $stateProvider
  .state('contactDetails', {
    url: '/contactDetails',
    views: {
      'contactDetails': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/contactDetails.html',
         controller: 'DemographicsController'
      }
    }
  });


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

});

module.controller("DemographicsController", function($state,$scope,$cordovaSQLite) {
 $scope.moveToNextPage= function() {
       $state.go('contactDetails');
    };
});
```

But, there is no reaction on the clicking the button .

Kindly help me finding the solution

Comment: Did you try debugging? Any errors visible in the console?

Comment: There is no error displaying in the console . Please tell me weather the way I am trying is correct or not.@iWörk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, Ionic uses ui-router for routing, that needs

`<div ui-view></div>`

In index.html

Or in ionic case

`<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>`

To work.

Secondly, I'd suggest you to write your route like:

`$stateProvider
  .state('contactDetails', {
    url: '/contactDetails',
    templateUrl: 'templates/contactDetails.html',
    controller: 'DemographicsController'
    }
  });`

Since there is more that one issue to address, lastly I'd suggest you to start your app with

`ionic start yourAppName tabs`

And try to play and understand how routing in ionic works. It's just so much easier to start when you have something to hack with and not only some plain app.